# OpenVPN missing bridge.ko

Tags: openvpn, network-bridge

Installing OpenVPN on a new server following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN).

I have gotten this working a couple times before but this time I get stuck getting the bridge driver to load.

Once the interface file has been configured to use br0 the network no longer will come up.

Manually trying to configure the bridge using

```
sudo brctl addbr br0
```

results in the error message

```
add bridge failed: Package not installed
```

Apparently this message comes from the kernel missing the module.  The config file in the boot folder has CONFIG_BRIDGE set to m which I understand means use the loadable module.  I understand this module is supposed to be bridge.ko.  Wikipedia says the modules should be in /lib/module but I seem to be missing the /lib/module folder entirely.

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS \n \l
uname -r
3.19.0-47-generic
```

`ifconfig -a` shows

```
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
        BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
        RX packets: 0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0  (0.0 B)

lo      Link encap:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr:  ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:150523 errors:0  dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:150523 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes:21426282 (21.4 MB)  TX bytes:21426282 (21.4MB)
```

Why is bridge.ko missing and/or how do I get it installed?

Comment: And what does `ifconfig -a` show?

Comment: `ifconfig -a` result added to question

Comment: OK. I'm not sure what is going wrong here, but it seems like you have perhaps misconfigured the interfaces file. I'm running 14.04 on my server, with an OpenVPN server, and don't recall ever having to poke about with manually adding a bridge with _brctl addbr_. Also, the kernel modules are installed in `/lib/modules/${uname -r}/`.

Comment: The comment about using `brctl addbr` wasn't saying that that was needed, but showing more details on what isn't working.  I am currently rebuilding the server from scratch.  Apparently something nuked the `/lib/modules` folder which then took out all the kernel modules.  As soon as I get the new server built up and working I will probably answer this question or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The `/lib/modules` directory somehow got deleted.  Reinstalling the OS from scratch fixed the problem.